# Can't quit PSQL on a mac (`which psql` goes to `/usr/local/php5/bin/psql`) which is odd

Tags: php, macos, postgresql

I have a weird situation where `which psql` is turing out to be `/usr/local/php5/bin/psql`.

I can't quit it, and it's an executable. Everything that I read online doesn't apply.

I tried doing:
`pg_ctl stop -D /usr/local/php5/bin/psql` 
And only got back `pg_ctl: could not open PID file "/usr/local/php5/bin/postgres/postmaster.pid": Not a directory`

`pg_ctl stop -D /usr/bin/psql`
Turns out to `pg_ctl: PID file "/usr/bin/psql/postmaster.pid" does not exist
Is server running?`

I have no idea what's going on.

Further more, I treid Postgres.app. When I started it, it said that the port was already being used. Now I can't even open the app because it's "somehow running", but doesn't show up anywhere. I know this because when I try to trash the app, it says it's currently running.

I already tried `brew remove postgresql` and there's nothing in `/Library`. I'm all out of ideas here and it seems like it has something to do with php5.

Any help would be really awsome.

EDIT:

So I got the correct `which psql` by changing my `.bachrc` path. That was pretty stupid of me. It now resolves to the app. My only concern is that `pc_ctl` still doesn't work to stop or anything alike.

Answer (score 1):

I actually had some paths set up from messing around with Laravel and Composer. That should have been the first thing I checked.

Finally, after removing those, I checked for any remaining postgres process ids which I could have done any number of ways, but just used ActivityMonitor this time.

Restarted Postgres.app. Checked for `~/Library/Application Support/Postgres` and made sure I removed it.

Followed [steps](http://postgresapp.com/documentation/install.html).